# Symfony 5 Add checkboxes from database in form when using MongoDB

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I am trying to create a Add User Form which should give me a list of available Roles as checkboxes from MongoDB. So I have a User and a Group Document and the UserType Form.

How can I display the available groups from my MongoDb in the user Form and save the ID's from the selected Group in the User Collection? Right now I am not even able to create the Form with the Groups displayed. The Error:

**Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given**

which is caused by the User document getGroups().

**group collection**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f11b2dbec17f922eb130e72"),
  "group_name" : "Admin",
}
```

**App\Form\UserType.php**

```
use App\Document\User;
use App\Document\Group;
use App\Repository\GroupRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Form\Type\DocumentType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ->add('username', TextType::class)

        ->add('groups', DocumentType::class, [
            'class' => Group::class,
        ])

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => User::class,
    ));
}
}
```

**App\Document\Group.php**

```
class Group
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $group_name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument=App\Document\User::class, inversedBy="groups")
 */
private $groupids;



public function getId(): ?string
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * @param string $group_name
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function getGroupName(): ?string
{
    return $this->group_name;
}

public function setGroupName(?string $group_name): self
{
    $this->group_name = $group_name;

    return $this;
}
}
```

**App\Document\User.php**

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="App\Document\Group", mappedBy="groupids")
 */
private $groups;


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}



/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getGroups(): array
{
    $groups = $this->groups;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER


    return array_unique($groups);
}

public function setGroups(array $groups): self
{
    $this->groups = $groups;

    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections initialize your collections. in general: use collection methods to modify your collections. the error probably occured for a new entity, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: either set the property `private $groups = [];` or do it in constructor. better would be to use collections, because doctrine will set your `$groups` to be a [collection](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php), which may be lazy-loaded and cause other "problems" if not handled properly.